# Smoothness and Lipschitz-continuous gradient

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

What is the relationship between $\mu$-smoothness and Lipschitz-continuous gradient?

A convex function $F : W \to \mathbb R$ is $\mu$-smooth with respect to some $w^*$ if for all $w\in W$: 
$$
F(w) - F(w^*) \le \frac{\mu}{2}||w-w^*||^2
$$

In https://icml.cc/Conferences/2012/papers/261.pdf the authors write:
"Such [$\mu$-smooth] functions arise, for instance, in logistic and leastsquares
regression, and in general for learning linear
predictors where the loss function has a Lipschitz-continuous
gradient"

Suppose I know the Lipschitz constant for $\nabla F$, how does this relate to $\mu$?

Comment: The definition is not correct: you have to include the term $-\nabla F(w^*)(w-w^*)$ on the left-hand side. In the paper they assume $w^*$ to be the minimum, hence $\nabla F(w^*)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds $\mu=L$:
$$
|f(x)-f(x^*)-\nabla f(x^*)(x-x^*)| 
\le\| \int_0^1  \nabla f(x+t(x-x^*))-\nabla f(x^*)dt\| \cdot \|x-x^*\|\\
\le \frac L2 \|x-x^*\|^2.
$$